# Multiline UILabel in self-sizing UITableViewCells with size-classes - iOS 8 & Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, constraints, size-classes

I'm having a problem with iOS 8 beta 4 ( and beta 5 also ) which is the UILabel is not showing all the text in the UITableViewCells. I used the self-sizing cells to make this, and one storyboard for all devices.

Here's what i get on the iPhone :-

[image: iphone screenshot]

Code :-

ViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell


    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.label.text  = "hello hello hello hellohellohellohellohello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hellohellohello hellohello hellohellohellohellohello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hellohellohello hello hello hello"
    case 1:
        cell.label.text  = "doesn'twork doesn'tworkdoesn't work doesn'twork doesn'tworkdoesn't work doesn'twork doesn'twork doesn't workdoesn't workdoesn'twork doesn'twork doesn't workdoesn't workdoesn't workdoesn'twork "
    case 2:
        cell.label.text  = "baims baimsbaimsbaims baimsbaimsbaimsbaims baims baimsbaims baimsbaimsbaimsbaims baimsbaims baims baimsbaimsbaims baimsbaims baims baimsbaimsbaimsbaims baimsbaims baimsbaims baimsbaims"
    default:
        cell.label.text  = "hello hello hello hellohellohellohellohello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hellohellohello hellohello hellohellohellohellohello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hellohellohello hello hello hello"
    }


    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

TableViewCell.swift

```
var label : UILabel!
var didUpdateConstraints = false

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {

    self.label = UILabel()
    self.label.textColor     = self.label.tintColor
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0

    self.label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.contentView.addSubview(self.label)
}

override func updateConstraints() {
    if !self.didUpdateConstraints {

        self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

        self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))

        self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

        self.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 13))


        self.didUpdateConstraints = true
    }

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

And here's my storyboard :-
[image: storyboard]

I think it was a bug in beta 4, but it should be fixed in beta 5 as the release notes says:

> Fixed in beta 5:
>   When the width of a multiline label changes due to changes in the layoutMargins of some view, the intrinsic content size of the label is not invalidated when it should be. As a result the layout can unexpectedly truncate the label (or text view). /// Workaround: The view whose layoutMargins are changing should override layoutMarginsDidChange and send invalidateIntrinsicContentSize to the label.

Comment: try adding self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension to your viewWillAppear()

Answer (score 0):

You are adding quite a large margin on your tableview through constraints, this is the distance to the edge. If you set this distance to 8 or `Standard`, this distance will be gone. This should solve the problem with the `TableViewCell` height too, if not, check out this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let label = // Get the label from the cell here
    return label.frame.size.height + 16 // Assuming you have 2 constraints on top & bottom, each 8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following lines to the "TableViewController":

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
...
```

setup the cell textLabel (multiline & wordwrap):

```
...
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell                
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
}
...
```

Remove the function (not needed anymore):

```
...
func override tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

}
...
```

That fits my multiline table view cells height automatically.